# How to get the attached gallery in the rest API?

Tags: api, rest-api

I just added a gallery to my post and want to access its images through the rest API. In the rest API, I can access the attachments of a post. But those attachments have other images, not in the gallery. For example, I just removed an image from the gallery and it's still there in the attachments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge this can't be done out of the box. So you could make use of what [`get_post_galleries()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_galleries) or [`get_post_gallery()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery), the latter is just making use of the former, are doing by adding an endpoint.

A minimal example could look like shown below.

```
function rest_get_post_gallery( $data ) {
    //set FALSE for data output
    $gallery = get_post_gallery( $data[ 'post_id' ], FALSE );

    if ( empty( $gallery ) ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    //comma separated list of ids
    return $gallery[ 'ids' ];
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'gallery_plugin/v1', '/post/(?P<post_id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'rest_get_post_gallery',
    ) );
} );
```

The following should give you a result now.

```
http://example.com/wp-json/gallery_plugin/v1/post/<post_id>
```

I based this on the article [Adding Custom Endpoints | REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/), so for further information take a look at it.

Comment: Great, it's working. Now need to see how to get an object per item containing the original source url and the dimensions.

Comment: `return $gallery;` only gives me a list of thumbnail images. How can I get the full image url along with the width and height?

Comment: @THpubs Take a look at [example data output](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_gallery#Example) for what information `get_post_gallery()` is providing you. Everything else you have to get, build yourself.